# Cut Loom screen recording at 39s, trim video around the edges to hide scrollbar and Loom stop button using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-casting

I have a 1920x1080 MP4 screencast that has been created in full-size mode in Google Chrome. I wish to hide the Loom video stopping process (after 39 seconds) and also trim around the edge of the video, so the browser scrollbar and Loom recording button are hidden during the video playback. Essentially cropping the inner 95% of the video.

How can I cut (crop) 95% of the video so the inner section is extracted? The proportions for 95% of the video would be 1824px x 1026px.

Here is the command to cut the video at 39 seconds. How could I combine with a crop command to hide the Loom browser recording process?

`ffmpeg -i LoomFullSizeScreenCast.mp4 -t 39 -c copy LoomFullSizeScreenCastCut.mp4`

Here is the video in action

https://thirsty-heisenberg-58e54e.netlify.com/LoomFullSizeScreenCast.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cropping is carried out using a video filter. Also, a filtered video has to be re-encoded. So the command would be

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf crop=1824:1026 -t 39 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See the docs for the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter for all options.

Comment: This is brilliant, thankyou - works a treat. It does end a bit abruptly with the cut. Is there any way to add 2 seconds to the start and finish? So the video would start at 2sec and finish at 43sec and perhaps still showing the still image you see if it was paused at 0:00

Comment: Do you wish to freeze the start of the input (t=0) for 2 seconds and then show 41s of the video?

Comment: Start playing video at 2s, showing the image of the video or what it like it would look if you paused at 0:00 and then add 2 seconds on the end, with the same attributes as 0:00 to 0:02

Comment: Found this answer by your good self which should do it. https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/ffmpeg-add-3-seconds-of-black-to-video-head-and-tail/20721

Comment: Use this instead with a recent version of ffmpeg, it's one-step: `-vf "crop=1824:1026,tpad=start_duration=2:start_mode=clone:stop_duration=2:stop_mode=clone" -af adelay=2s`